# better way to throw exception when return type is promise

Tags: node.js, typescript

What is the better way to define return type for an asynchronous operation that returns a promise or Error?

Does the following make sense?

```
public async findUserByUsername(username: string, context: IDataContext): Promise<IUser | Error> {
    const user = await this.collection.findOne({ username: username });
    if (user) {
        user.id = user._id;
        return user;
    }
    return new Error(`user not found`);
}
```

Is there another way to define return type that `throws errors`?

Comment: just throw to throw them and handle them later in a .catch callback.

Comment: Don't do that. you can have several levels of methods where each and every single one of those throws different errors. 

e.g. 
A calls B, B calls C, C calls D... 

Then A might have to specify w/e is not handled in B, C, D... 

The method you wrote will have to specify multiple errors. It becomes bloated. You will be having long function signatures because you specified multiple error types.

Use jsdocs
   /**
   * @throws {Error}
   */ 

and proper error handling. Every editor recognizes the syntax and your eyes wont hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`never` type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) is what you're looking for.

```
public async findUserByUsername(username: string, context: IDataContext): Promise<IUser | never> {
    const user = await this.collection.findOne({ username: username });
    if (user) {
        user.id = user._id;
        return user;
    }
    throw new Error(`user not found`);
}
```

**Update:**
You can throw an error and indicate with the never type that an exception can be thrown in this function. TypeScript does not know any way to tell that a function throws an specific exception like Java does.

Comment: @manu what if we have a wrapper around the error like `UserNotFound`. Do you want me to update the question here?

Comment: @user1595858 I updated the answer. Normally an error is thrown and caught with try { } catch {}. This also works with async await and Promise.

Comment: never is only a meaningful syntax that will catch developers' eye. it doesn't do much actually. 

never is always absorbed into the return statement the same way 'something || false' depends on 'something'. 

I would prefer and suggest using jsdocs for this purpose because all the editors will catch this and show you if you hovering over that method. 

  /**
   * @throws {VError, CustomError,...}
   */